# Why flutter snackBar not working inside if statement?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, snackbar

I have coded a `SnackBar` inside the if condition, if the condition is true it has to show `SnackBar` but it's not happening even when the condition is true.

this is my code

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      await fetch();
      await _scan();
      setState(() {
        total = initial! + last!;
      });
      if (total.toString() == scanResult.rawContent){
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar)                                 
      }
    },
    child: Text("scan")),
```

I don't know why it's not working when even the condition is true

Comment: Can you show your snackBar code?

Comment: final snackBar = SnackBar(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 20),
  content: Text('scan again ..'),
);   @Yashraj

Comment: I have checked and its works on my PC.

Comment: You need to provide more snippet how you are passing context, means where and how you are showing the snackBar

Comment: i have just updated the code with the snippet sir, please check and help @Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: i have just updated the code with the snippet sir, please check and help @Yashraj

Comment: if (total.toString() == scanResult.rawContent) is true then you need to show Snackbar right?

Answer (score 0):

use `ScaffoldMessenger` outside the `setState`

```dart
onPressed: () async {
    await fetch();
    await _scan();
  total = initial! + last!;
    setState(() { });      
    if(total.toString() == scanResult.rawContent){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar) ;   
     }}
```

Comment: still not working bro @Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: try checking `otal.toString() == scanResult.rawContent` is true

Comment: i tried bro, it's still not working for some reason i dont understand , i tried using a alret dailog box it's too not working   @Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: Can you check if the condition is really true, like do a print state inside the if method